# reading audio encoding

Tags: c#, audio, core-audio

I have wave files that I want to read their header content. I was just wondering if there is a quick library I  can use or any free software that I can open my audio with, and gives me some usefull header information.

Answer (score 0):

What platform?  For the PC, you can use the mmioDescend API to walk the RIFF structure of the WAV file.

Answer (score 0):

See AudioFileInfoCs from http://alvas.net/Download/Alvas.Audio.zip